# Can the basics of elastic search be implemented using a nosql database?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can the basics of elastic search be implemented using a nosql database by performing the following steps? For each document to index:

1. Generate n-grams from text
2. Insert n-gram into table where the n-gram is the key and a list of matching documents is the value

Comment: are you asking how to do an Elasticsearch feature in another different nosql datastore?

Comment: Yes. I'm asking if elasticsearch is essentially like a nosql store where the n-grams in the text are the keys and a list of corresponding documents is the value.

Comment: Look like you try to explain the "Inverted index" algorithm, used by Elasticsearch (Lucene). Is this basic of Elasticsearch? Yes. Is this anough for "like Elasticsearch" implementation? I think No, but it depends by your use case. At least you'll need а search algorythm (idf-tf) or any other. But if all that you need is exact matches quick finding, maybe this good anough. If you talk about Big Data maybe you'll need any shard algorithm e.t.c.
So, this is "litle bit" complicate question, and vary hard to answer without knowing your use case.

Answer (score -1):

your question is a little confusing here, as Elasticsearch is a [nosql datastore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/documents-indices.html) and it can [create ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html). you can also search for a word/value and then return matching documents

perhaps explaining a little more on what you are trying to achieve, ie the use case, would help provide a clearer answer